# Find transfer function from state space representation

Tags: transfer-function, state-space

The following system is given : $$\dot{\bar x}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\-1&-2&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&-3 \end{bmatrix}\bar x+\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-1&0\\0&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}=A\bar x+B\bar u\\$$

$$y=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\bar x$$

After calculations I found $$Y(s)=\frac{-U_1(s)}{(s+1)}+\frac{3U_2(s)}{s+3}$$

The problem follows: Let $$\bar u=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}+\bar r$$

Now how do I find $$\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}$$ How does my transfer function change? Will it still depend on U1 and U2?

Comment: It's a linear system, so superposition applies.

Comment: @Chu I think there is a mistake here when he introduces u=1 1 u1 u2 +r. We can't multiply this by B. Can you guess what he meant to write?

Comment: Seems there are two separate systems

Comment: We can't do the matrix multiplication with B with the dimensions given in the new u.

Comment: There's certainly a dimension mismatch between B and U. I've drawn the controller canonical block diagram and there are two separate feedback systems with separate input signals and a composite output signal. If I were to guess, I'd tie the two inputs together and call that new input 'r', that will allow Y/R to be determined. Come back and tell us what the correct answer (and question!) are when you find out.